# If I build a type with a property using TypeBuilder do I need to use a propertyBuilder?

Tags: c#

I want to use TypeBuilder to build a type that matches an interface. It's base type will be object, as I don't have any abstraction point.

The interface in question has a property like so::

```
public interface IFoo{
    int Property{get;}
}
```

Do I need to actually create a PropertyBuilder? Or can I just get away with emitting a method for the `int get_Property()` method?

Comment: +1 Interesting question. The only time I've ever dynamically created a Type, I just used public fields so as not to have to muck around with PropertyBuilders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CLI doesn't care about properties, as long as all the methods (which is all an interface *really* defines) have implementations:

```
var ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
    new AssemblyName("foo"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("foo");
var tb = mb.DefineType("bar");
tb.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IFoo));
var method = typeof(IFoo).GetProperty("Property").GetGetMethod();
var impl = tb.DefineMethod("impl",
    MethodAttributes.Private | MethodAttributes.Virtual,
    typeof(int), Type.EmptyTypes);
var il = impl.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_7); // because it is lucky
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
tb.DefineMethodOverride(impl, method);

var type = tb.CreateType();
IFoo foo = (IFoo)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var val = foo.Property;
```

Comment: Thank you! This'll make my duck taper easier, but why do you do MethodOverride if the method wasn't actually defined on the type?

Comment: @Michael - because that is how you tell it what method provides the implementation. Interface methods are technically implicit virtual methods if you look at the CLI flags.

Comment: ah cool. If I declare a public virtual method called get_Property it seems to work as well. I guess this is needed if I want to add different implementations for multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you need to use a PropertyBuilder - a Property in .Net isn't as simple as having get_ and/or set_ methods - there's extra metadata needed.

I've never used TypeBuilder though, but I'd be pretty surprised if you could get away with just emitting a get_ method.

Comment: Surprising or not, you *can* just emit a get method - in fact, it doesn't need to be `get_` *at all*.

Comment: Well I learned something new today.  Is there somewhere good I can read up about CLI oddities?